# Check if memory is allocated for temporary arrays across functions

Tags: eigen3

The program has a function A that calls an inline function B.

`#define EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC` is at top of the program.

If I put `Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(false);` within function A, would that check for memory allocation in both A and B when I call A?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_is_malloc_allowed(false)` is a global function which sets a global flag (More accurately: A static variable inside a global function). Therefore, it will prohibit memory allocations (inside Eigen) until `set_is_malloc_allowed(true)` is called at any place.

You can check if memory currently is allowed using `is_malloc_allowed()`.